# Can't find disk partition to install windows server

Tags: windows-server-2012, hp-proliant

I bought the HP home Proliant microserver gen 8 , and i m trying to install Windows Server 2012 from a bootable USB .

I created a bootable USB drive with a Windows Server 2012 iso image and i boot the system from the USB . The windows setup starts normally , but when the prompt for the "type of installation" comes out and i m choosing the "custom:Install Windows only" option the system can't find any disk partitions to install Windows .

When i Choose to go to intelligent provisioning mode  ,then select the `perform maintentance` option and finally click on `HP smart Storage admininstrator` , i can see a Dynamic Smart Array B120i RAID 1 . There is 1 logical drive and 2 physical drives of 1 TB each .

I don't know what's wrong with my procedure please advise and ask for any further details .

Comment: You need to add the raid drivers, windows doesn't know about any storage beyond basic storage methods.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem but I solved it by unplugging the Mini SAS connector.  Apparently the Windows Setup gets confused by the RAID array in the four drive bays.  Now install was able to find space on a single drive, no problem.

Comment: In my case the problem was some hp drivers i needed to install for the server to recognize the hard disks

Answer (score 2):

I just installed Windows Server 2019 succesfully after like 20 hours of trying...

What I had to to:

- Create a RAID partition under 2 TB for booting (I've a 4 TB drive) (press F5)
- Mark that partition bootable (F5 too)
- Use front USB port
- **Put the B120i RAID Controller drivers on the Windows USB Drive**
- **Replace the CMOS Battery**

I replaced the CMOS Battery after like 20 hours (inluding sleep). Then booted up the computer and before I'd opened the Remote Console the installation had begun and I could select the 500 GB OS partition I'd created.

---

*Story behind the battery change: it took me a while but suddenly I noted that the time wasn't consistent on the computer. After a nights sleep I decided to replace the battery. Someone had written in some other post that the RAID controller needs a good battery.*

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with my HP Proliant ML130e. Installing Hyper-V Core 2019 all goes well until the second restart. Then a loading loop on the Windows boot screen.

I found this and thought it insightful.

From his Post: (HPE forum)
I refused to give up on this and I've stumbled on the following from HPE in this document:  https://www.hpe.com/h20195/V2/getpdf.aspx/4AA5-5841ENW.pdf

Possible solution

Table 5. Known issues and workarounds.

Description of issue

ML310e Gen8 v2 will not boot after enabling the Hyper-V role.

Workaround/Solution

Ensure ROM settings are configured with VT enabled and VT-D disabled before enabling the Hyper-V role.

I implemented the BIOS option. It worked like a charm.