# Unable to install Windows Server

Tags: windows, raid, hp-proliant, windows-server-2016

I'm documenting this here as I spent ~3 days on and off trying to get my head around these specific problems and there was surprisingly little on the web.

---

I have a HP ProLiant Gen8 G1610T which I want to use as a media server so I bought 2 x 4 TB WD RED HDDs to stripe for ~8 TB of storage capacity.

---

**Attempt #1**

I:

1. Used the Smart Storage Administrator to create a 8 TB RAID 0 / striped volume.
2. Booted to a Windows installer USB flash drive (Rufus + `SW_DVD9_Win_Svr_STD_Core_and_DataCtr_Core_2016_64Bit_English_-2_MLF_X21-22843.ISO`).
3. Loaded the driver HP Dynamic Smart Array B120i/B320i SATA RAID Controller (http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=5387585&swItemId=MTX_07615039b81a44fda3bf51e9ac&swEnvOid=4231).
4. Selected the ~7.2 TiB volume.
5. Installed Windows Server 2016 Standard.

This worked fine but there was only a 2 TB partition which couldn't be extended as it was initialized as MBR.

---

**Attempt #2**

As advised by http://www.thewindowsclub.com/convert-mbr-to-gpt-disk, I tried to convert the partition from MBR to GPT but it didn't work.

---

**Attempt #3**

I looked for how to change the "BIOS mode" from legacy to UEFI to allow booting to a GPT-initialized drive but, according to many sources (https://community.hpe.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-Netservers/Microserver-Gen8-UEFI/td-p/6499756, http://homeservershow.com/forums/index.php?/topic/9643-how-to-enable-uefi-in-microserver-gen8/, https://community.hpe.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-ML-DL-SL/ML350p-Gen-8-UEFI-bios/td-p/6293177), the only HP ProLiant Gen8 to support UEFI is the DL580.

---

**Attempt #4**

I cleared the RAID config and did the same as attempt #1 except created seperate 250 GB and 7.75 TB RAID 0 / striped volumes and selected the former to install but this time I encountered the following errors:

> Windows can't be installed on this drive (Show details)

> Windows cannot be installed to this disk. This computer's hardware may not support booting to this disk. Ensure that the disk's controller is enabled in the computer's BIOS menu.

> We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one. For more information, see the Setup log files.

[image]
[image]

---

**Attempt #5**

I used Command Prompt / `diskpart` to clean, partition, format, active, assign etc both RAID volumes but still encountered the same errors.

---

**Attempt #6**

I cleared the RAID config and did the same as attempt #1 except created only a 250 GB striped volume but still encountered the same errors.

---

**Attempt #7**

I cleared the RAID config and did the same as attempt #1 but still encountered the same errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find disk partition to install windows server](https://serverfault.com/questions/810879/cant-find-disk-partition-to-install-windows-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During my extensive DuckDuckGo- and Google-ing, I read something that recommended removing all USB drives but I dismissed that thinking "What? I'm installing off of a USB flash drive? How would that work?"

Apparently, the problem was indeed that a USB flash drive was connected - my **other** USB flash drive (the one containing the RAID controller driver).

Connecting my other USB flash drive **post-boot** worked absolutely fine.

This is what I unknowingly did in attempt #1 - I booted into the Windows installer, saw that it didn't have a driver for the RAID controller, downloaded it on my PC to my other USB flash drive, and **then** connected it.

Bizarre but there you have it.

Also, I don't know if it's relevant but the problematic USB flash drive is USB 3.0 and has FalconFour installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by **replacing the CMOS battery** as it was old. Everything else was correctly setup with the RAID. No other settings done. Installed using USB.