# Microserver Gen8 cannot install windows server 2012R2 does not see HDD or drivers for it

Tags: raid, windows-server-2012-r2, hp-proliant, licensing

first time posting here. 
I have a problem with installing Windows server 2012 R2 on HP Microserver Gen8 that I have been struggling for acouple of days. I searched over forum but I can't find the solution for this. I don't have CD slot so I use USB for boot iso. When I try to install it using IP at the end I get "Windows can not find the Microsoft Software License terms..." error and I can't go past that. (I have product key but I needed to download .iso from Microsoft pages). I tried to go manual install but I can't see any HDD. When I try to load drivers I downloaded from HP pages (RAID controller driver). I can't select driver windows cannot see them either. Now I'm getting pretty frustrated I have a brand new server which obviously does not respond to the evaluation copy of windows, and hp driver which cannot be seen windows?? Don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try entering the BIOS and setting the HDD in IDE mode. Does it change anything?

Comment: Thank You very much for your response, but I managed to solve the problem. I unziped driver and windows recognized driver when pointed to folder with unziped .exe , even though I still have some troubles after win server is now up and running.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find disk partition to install windows server](https://serverfault.com/questions/810879/cant-find-disk-partition-to-install-windows-server)